# Force bit.ly to create a bit.ly link instead of on.fb.me

Tags: facebook, api, bit.ly

I have a link to a facebook app and i need it to be shortened with bit.ly. Unfortunally it always shortens it to on.fb.me. My client is a bit unhappy with that. There must be some solution because i've seen other pages still having bit.ly links with a facebook app behind it.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

There are two options. You can set the preferred domain to j.mp (add `&domain=j.mp` when shortening), or set up a [custom short domain](http://support.bitly.com/knowledgebase/articles/76741-how-do-i-set-up-a-custom-short-domain-). `bit.ly` and `bitly.com` have the lowest priority, but your own (or your client's own) short domain has the highest. There's a little more info in the [docs for the /v3/shorten](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_shorten) endpoint.